# In elisp, how can I convert a string to an escaped string?

Tags: dired, shell-command

In DirEd, when I copy a filename, using

```
C-u 0 w
```

, it's copied fine, but I can't use this string in a shell command, cause it's not escaped.

Is there a function to convert a string to an escaped string?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't use this string in a shell command

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `shell-quote-argument` is the function which performs shell-specific escaping.  Any time you're building a shell command programmatically, you should pass variable arguments to that function.

In your interactive `dired` case, though... surely you want to use <kbd>!</kbd> to run a shell command with the current file (or marked files) as an argument?

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `dired-do-shell-command` for details.